# I am not able to run jupyter notebook after installation in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter

I installed jupyter on my ubuntu system via the following command :

```
sudo pip install jupyter
```

After executing it I could run `jupyter notebook` successfully.
But unfortunately while trying to upgrade it for python3, I accidentally deleted all `jupyter` links from my `/usr/local/bin`.
Now `jupyter notebook` is not running. I have tried un-installing and re-installing also.
I have no clue about what should I do now.

Comment: If you've upgraded to pyhton3 you might want to try installing jupter using pip3 `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` then `sudo pip3 install jupyter`

Comment: @Jack Evans I have tried this also. I get that jupyter is already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't install python packages with sudo unless you really know what you're doing.

Try this instead:

```
$ virtualenv myvenv
$ cd myvenv
$ source bin/activate
$ pip install jupyter
$ jupyter notebook
```

To run it the next time (in a new shell session i.e), simply do:

```
$ cd myvenv
$ source bin/activate
$ jupyter notebook
```

Comment: yes it is working now. But what do I do when I want to run it the next time